# Getting error when opening Interface Builder (Mac OS X Lion)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos, sdk

I'm using a 13" Macbook Pro. I'm beginning a project for University; I'm making an iPhone application. I bought the DevKit but had some problems opening Xcode, I realiased I'd upgraded to Lion since I downloaded it and needed to upgrade, so I did, so Xcode 4.3.

Now I can use Xcode fine (as far as I can tell) but Interface Builder gives me this error when I try to make a new iPhone Application Template/Project:

This version of Interface Builder does not support documents of type "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Document (XIB 3.x)" targeting "iPhone/iPod touch".

And this one if I try to make a blank one, of any other the other options:

Interface Builder was unable to open the document "Empty.xib".  iPhone/iPod touch development requires the iOS 3.1 SDK.

Now, I checked, and according the the AppStore (which is where I was forced to download it from) iOS 5.0/5.1 SDK is included. I tried to redownload a few times but to no avail. I have a feeling this is something really stupid, so feel free to call me so.

Comment: Can you open xib files in Xcode itself? Interface builder is no longer a separate app since Xcode 4.0

Comment: Check what version of Xcode you are actually running - it might still be the old one if you're just clicking the same dock icon. There is no separate IB any more, as vin says.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Xcode itself to create, view, and modify xib files for iOS 5 projects. Interface Builder as a separate application is no longer provided by Apple for iOS development.

Xcode 4 allows creation of user interface files from the `File > New > New File` menu item. When you select a user interface file from Xcode's project navigator (which you can show via `View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator` or by pressing Cmd-1), a user interface editor appears where the source code editor typically appears.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But what I don't understand is... Where do I use the functionality of Interface Builder now? As it doesn't seem to be built into Xcode 4.0+

Comment: Thanks bneely, I can't believe I didn't realise that. Probably wasted 3-4 days of development ha! I'd upvote you but I'm not allowed with this being a new account :).